# How do I fix the error, "Unexpected token (1:61)" in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn react and I have a problem. In Visual Studio Code, in the terminal, I first entered `npx create-react-app .` then `npm start` and this error appeared:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:61)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/MY DIRECTORY TO THIS PROJECT/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
```

I have looked all over for an answer to this problem, however nothing I found worked.
I did try to add the

```
$RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/MY DIRECTORY TO THIS PROJECT/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
$RefreshSetup$(module.id);
```

to my index.js file but the same error occurred.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thanks so much for any help! :)

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you running? Adding those lines to your Index.js is probably a red herring.

Comment: Can you add `index.js`?

Comment: @zero298 I added index.js to my question.

Comment: @AKX I am currently using Node.js version 12.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular issue is [apparently](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10518#issuecomment-775476713) a bug with the newest version of react-scripts. According to the linked comment, downgrading to 4.0.1 will help:

> Update - I went into the `package.json` and changed the react-scripts to 4.0.1 and re-ran `npm install` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional loader as the error represents.

Checkout this library. It's targeting the new HMR loading issues.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-refresh-loader

Comment: Where is the webpack.config.js file located? It is not in the root of the project. This is my first time working with react.

Comment: OP can't configure Webpack if they're using Create React App.

Answer (score 0):

I had already that problem with react, but you can fix it.
At first open

> package.json

and change `react-scripts` to `4.01`, after that open up terminal and type `npm install`. it will fix.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30087078)